# Does H.A.W.X. 2 have Always On DRM?

Tags: h.a.w.x.-2

Does this game still have Always On DRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Hawx 2 still has the always on DRM. I didn't see it anywhere on the Hawx 2 site (I assume because it is not much of a selling point) but the [steam store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/48160/) page warns about it:

> A PERMANENT HIGH SPEED INTERNET CONNECTION AND CREATION OF A UBISOFT
>   ACCOUNT ARE REQUIRED TO PLAY THIS GAME.

Comment: Do you own the game? Did you try it out yourself? They could have just forgotten to edit the store page over on Steam. I need a reliable answer, I can read system requirements myself.

Comment: Fine give me an hour to redownload and I'll test it again... as of Oct it still had it.

Comment: Yep the always on DRM is still there and as a side note I only have one activation left, so the activation limit is still there too.